# Detecting similar behaviour in audio files

Tags: audio, python, algorithms, machine-learning

Can anyone help, I'm trying to find a solution that would allow me the ability to look at a batch of .WAV files and detect ones which share a similar behaviour in the recording like the image attached.

Recording -> Large Gap -> Recording

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for large sections of silence or do you need to identify regions with similar, non-silent content?

Comment: Also, is that silence literally zero-values or just a little bit of analog noise potentially from from the recording hardware?

Comment: Have you looked at computing the energy of the signal and thresholding? The section of the signal with zero value should have zero energy.